# How to include description in JSON file using Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, system.text.json

I'm starting using C# and have a lot to learn.

I'm trying to create a JSON file with a dictionary (thats easy).

JsonSerializer.Serialize(MyDictionary)

But it returns the data without descriptions...

```
{
               "-0255504",
               "1"
            },
            {
               :"08000301",
               :"1"
            }
```

I want to to include some descriptions like:

```
{
               "ArticleId":"-0255504",
               "OrderedQuantity":"1"
            },
            {
               "ArticleId":"08000301",
               "OrderedQuantity":"1"
            },
            {
               "ArticleId":"03820235",
               "OrderedQuantity":"1"
            }
```

For sure is easy to include and don't want to use List for my program.

Is available any method or property to modify the format?

I'm Using  System.Text.Json;

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: The first JSON sample shown in your question is not well-formed.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get *`Error: Parse error on line 2:`*.  Can you share a [mcve] showing how you generated that JSON?  I am surprised that [tag:system.text.json] would generate such malformed JSON.  We can't really tell you how to generate well-formed JSON with the required properties without knowing what you are doing currently that is not working.  See: [ask].

Comment: This is the result of the Json:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can project your dictionary items into anonymous (or not anonymous) types to get your property names:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "-0255504", "1" },
                { "-08000301", "1" },
            };

  string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(d.Select(entry => new { ArticleId = entry.Key, OrderedQuantity = entry.Value }));
```

Comment: OMG

Thank you so much!!! 

I lost 2 days in this :-D